# Django - Create or Update reverse foreign key object from parents DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I would like to Create or Update a Child object when on the Parent object DetailView.

I have two models, as follows:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'Parent', related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have the following view:

```
 class ParentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Parent
```

What would be the best approach to allow the Creating or Updating of a Child object whilst on the ParentDetailView ?

I have seen the following approach in Django docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "key", so to speak, is to use the primary_key parameter when creating a new field in a model class object. Consider this a modified part of an Account model from my program.

```
class Account(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   posts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The email field is set so that it is a primary_key that can be used to access this particular Account object from a program. Lets see it in views.py:

```
email = request.COOKIES.get('email')   
user = Account.objects.get(pk=email)
user.posts = users.posts + 1
user.save()
```

Cool so we can update that object. You can also create a new one, and you don't have to define every field, but you do need to make sure they have default values for the database in models.py.

```
new_acc = Account(username = form_username, email = form_email, password = form_password)
new_acc.save()
```

Now, if you're super cool and with it you don't even wanna save personal information as a cookie. check it

```
class Account(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   uuid = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='defaultforDB')
```

Creating in views.py

```
   new_acc = Account(username = form_username, email = form_email, password = form_password, uuid = unique_uuid)
   new_acc.save()
```

Now I still want to be able to find my account with only an email. So I created another ProfileKey model where the impersonal information username is used and stored locally on the browser to access my database.

```
    if not(request.COOKIES.get('user', 'default') == 'default'):
       user = request.COOKIES.get('user')
       uuid = request.COOKIES.get('uuid')
       userDB_uuid = (Account.objects.get(pk=(ProfileKey.objects.get(pk=(user))).email)).uuid
    if uuid == userDB_uuid:
        return render(request, 'forum/personalhome.html', {'form':form, 'user':user})
```

In general, create the object. Use save. Find the object, change a value, use save.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I don't think this quite answers my question.

Comment: To create a child object simply call the default constructor with the values for the fields required. The foreignkey will be directly tied to the other model so that you can use it as a for primary_key to access the main model. Then you can just change the fields in each object as you require and run a save()

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted my question. This is not of any help.